# A "twisted" limit of the function $F(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function (not necessarily continuous). Suppose for any $y>0$, we have $\lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x,y)=0$. Does there necessarily exist a positive-valued function $g(x)$, again not necessarily continuous, with $\lim_{x\to +\infty} g(x)=0$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x,g(x)) = 0 ?$$

I have tried many examples for such $F(x,y)$ and found they all work. To rigorously prove this, one basically need to construct $g(x)$ so that it goes to zero "sufficiently slow". I don't know how to prove this or give a counterexample.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha What happens when $F(x,y) = \frac{y}{x}$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $(0,0) \in \Bbb R^2$, domain of $F$, so, $F(0,0)$ must be defined.

Comment: @Aman "be a function (not necessarily continuous)" is the real constraint. Fill in the hole piecewise however you like, your example clearly does not work.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, I agree.

Comment: Find $x_1$ so that $x\geq x_1$ implies $|F(x,1)|<1$ for all $x\geq x _1$. Now find $x_2>x_1$ so that $|F(x,1/2)|<1/2$ for all $x\geq x_2$. Continuing in this way, we obtain an increasing sequence of points $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ such that $|F(x,1/n)|<1/n$  for all $x\geq x_n$. We can choose these points $\{x_n\}$ in such a way so that $\{x_n\}$ diverges to $+\infty$. Now if you put $$g(x)=1_{(-\infty,x_1)}(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}1_{[x_n,x_{n+1})}(x)$$ then I believe this $g$ satisfies both conditions.